# How to compare time in objc

Tags: objective-c, nsdate

I want to a Countdown,show Day,Hour,M and S. a second is called once.

```
- (void)changetime {     

    NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];//定义一个NSCalendar对象                 
    NSDate *today = [NSDate date];//得到当前时间

    unsigned int unitFlags = NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit;
    NSDateComponents *weekdayComponents =[cal components:(unitFlags) fromDate:self.overDate]; 
    NSDate *todate = [cal dateFromComponents:weekdayComponents]; 
    NSDateComponents *d = [cal components:unitFlags fromDate:today toDate:todate options:0];

    NSInteger days=[d year]*365+[d month]*31+[d day];
    if ([self.overDate earlierDate:[NSDate date]]==self.overDate) {
        [myTimer invalidate];
        myTimer=nil;
        self.labdate.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d天%d时%d分%d秒",days, [d hour], [d minute], [d second]];
        return;
    }    
    self.labdate.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d天%d时%d分%d秒",days, [d hour], [d minute], [d second]];     
}

myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(changetime) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

self.overDate=[wedding date];//this is a future time
```

Answer (score 2):

The following line should cause you alarm:

```
NSInteger days=[d year]*365+[d month]*31+[d day];
```

There are only 365 days in a year ~75% of the time in the Gregorian calendar. Nearly 50% of months don't have 31 days in that calendar. Review the [Date Calculations](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/Articles/dtCalendricalCalculations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007836-SW1) section in Apple's documentation, which tells you that if you ask for the Day component and nothing bigger in your `components:fromDate:toDate:options:` call, you'll get the number of days you need taking calendars into account.